# How do I locate a black box for a black box retrieval mission?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I picked up a mission to retrieve a black box in a specific system, and I've gotten to that system, but now I'm at a lost as to what to do next. I've done some looking online which suggested to just do a discovery scan of the system and that should reveal it, but it didn't reveal one as far as I can tell. I also read I could go to the nav beacon as well, but when I go to the nav beacon nothing actually happens (although it's possible I'm not close enough).

[image]

[image]

I'm rather at a loss as to what to do next. How do I locate and then retrieve the black box for the mission I'm on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says on the tin, "search signal sources in the Brani system". The mission black box will spawn at a signal source somewhere in that system.

You can scan the nav beacon to possibly identity which one in particular by traveling to the beacon, targeting it, and facing your ship towards it for about 10 seconds or so, but this will not always reveal additional information. You will get a mission update about this whether or not you got additional info from the beacon.

Comment: So I ended up competing this, and I basically just flew around until I got some notification about the black box, which seems like is what you're supposed to do then.